# How to make Firefox urlbar prioritize most visited url's, including sub domains?

Tags: firefox

I frequently visit a site on a sub domain. When typing the first letter of the site's url, all other browsers auto fills the rest, but Firefox needs the entire subdomain and a dot before recognizing it, as it seems to prioritize domain names above anything else.

Are there any setting to change this behavior, so Firefox doesn't distinct between sub domains and domains, and simply uses the most frequently visited sites for suggestions?